# Problem of choosing over time

Tags: probability

I have a set of 100 diseased people. According to data, the probability of them getting themselves reported/tested is 0.03, which means that only 1 in every 30 cases will get reported. Let us assume that the count of the diseased remains a constant over 10 days. How should the probability of reporting/testing be interpreted? Should I expect that at the end of 10 days there should only be 3-4 cases or 30-35 (assuming that 3-4 get reported daily)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am assuming that $(0.97)$ fraction of the patients absolutely never report the disease.  For the $(0.03)$ that do report the disease, how long does it typically take for them to report the disease, 1 day, 2 days, 10 days, 30 days, ...?  Also, how does anyone ever get *off* the list of the diseased, is it by a cure?  If so, one might surmise that the new cases reported each day exactly balance the people who are pronounced cured, each day.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, you are right 0.97 fraction never report. The under-reporting factor is currently provided for the cumulative cases. No further details on the average time to report the disease is known. One gets off the diseased list by being cured and immune to the disease or succumbing to it (death).

Comment: Are the $100$ people the ones who have the disease, or the $3$% of those who have the disease who reported it?  Also, if $3.5$ cases get reported each day, that means that you are actually getting about $117$ new cases a day, of which most of them are never reported.  Further, if you are adding $3.5$ new cases a day, and the count of the disease is staying constant, that means that about $3.5$ people are going off the list each day, because they are cured.